# When should you not use the 'Builder Design Pattern' to create objects?

Tags: java

I was just curious if there was any time you would not use a 'Builder Design Pattern' to create objects.

Comment: Did you read [this](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/07/builder-design-pattern-in-java.html)?

Comment: From what I understand a  builder wouldn't be a good match for when the object you are trying to create is based on an `interface`.  That is, the actual implementation is unknown at run time, then you'd use a factory

Comment: @JoshM Thanks I read the 'Effective Java' book. The only thing I don't really understand is 'as Factory can be used to create different implementation of same interface'

Comment: @JoshM @MadProgrammer Thanks, I think I have been using the factory design pattern without realising it is called that. Normally where I use an `Enum` and overriding methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The builder design  pattern is  used to create a  complex object from simple ones step by step. If this is not your case, you should not use builder design pattern

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you do not use builders when all your object's fields are required upon construction. In that case using a simple constructor might be enough, unless you see some other applicable creational patterns, such as factory or singleton.

Builders can also affect the size of your distribution. You may opt to not use the pattern when you don't want a bulk of classes, especially if you are distributing a library.

Object creation using builder patterns may also be replaced by using other languages or lambda (a feature in Java 8). In case, you prefer using those, then it would be alright for you to not use builders.